# Itextsharp text extraction

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using itextsharp on vb.net to get the text content from a pdf file. The solution works fine for some files but not for other even quite simple ones. The problem is that the token stringvalue is set to null (a set of empty square boxes)

```
token = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser(pageBytes)
    While token.NextToken()
        tknType = token.TokenType()
        tknValue = token.StringValue
```

I can meassure the length of the content but I cannot get the actual string content.

I realized that this happens depending on the font of the pdf. If I create a pdf using either Acrobat or PdfCreator with Courier (that by the way is the default font in my visual studio editor) I can get all the text content. If the same pdf is built using a different font I got the empty square boxes.

Now the question is, How can I extract text regardless of the font setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 46):

complementary for Mark's answer that helps me a lot .iTextSharp implementation namespaces and classes are a bit different from java version

```
 public static string GetTextFromAllPages(String pdfPath)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath); 

        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();  

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) 
            output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for giving a full example of the code, rather than just a single line

Comment: is it possible to extract file on 'ftp server' using itextsharp?

Comment: @Munavvar , unfortunately I did not have such an experience. but usually you can read from FTP in frs of File stream or binaries and feed the ItextSharp

Comment: Returns an empty (only white spaces) sometimes what could be the possible cause?

Comment: @Nerdintraining, please more exact on sometimes , maybe when abnormal pdf formats is passed or maybe when the page is actually an image which must be OCRed first.

Comment: You know that with image might be correct! Do you know off your head if there is a way to detect if the PDF contains images? and if so how to extract them?

Comment: @Nerdintraining , No unfortunately I do not have any experience with that

Comment: Darn okay, i will add it as comment here if i find something

Answer (score 13):

Check out [PdfTextExtractor](http://api.itextpdf.com/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html).

```
String pageText = 
  PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(myReader, pageNum);
```

or

```
String pageText = 
  PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(myReader, pageNum, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

Both require fairly recent versions of iText[Sharp].  Actually parsing the content stream yourself is just reinventing the wheel at this point.  Spare yourself some pain and let iText do it for you.

PdfTextExtractor will handle all the different font/encoding issues for you... all the ones that can be handled anyway.  If you can't copy/paste from Reader accurately, then there's not enough information present in the PDF to get character information from the content stream.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variant with iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS and iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENT if some one need it.

```
        string strFile = @"C:\my\path\tothefile.pdf";
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfRida = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(strFile);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser prtTokeneiser;
        int pageFrom = 1;
        int pageTo = pdfRida.NumberOfPages;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.TokType tkntype ;
        string tknValue;

        for (int i = pageFrom; i <= pageTo; i++) 
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary cpage = pdfRida.GetPageN(i);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray cannots = cpage.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS);

            if(cannots!=null)
                foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject oAnnot in cannots.ArrayList) 
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary cAnnotationDictironary = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary)pdfRida.GetPdfObject(((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference)oAnnot).Number);

                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject moreshit = cAnnotationDictironary.Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS);
                    if (moreshit != null && moreshit.GetType() == typeof(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfString)) 
                    {
                        string cStringVal = ((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfString)moreshit).ToString();
                        if (cStringVal.ToUpper().Contains("LOS 8"))
                        { // DO SOMETHING FUN

                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        pdfRida.Close();
```