# Convert PDF to text without pdftotext?

Tags: pdf, pdftotext

I have to convert PDFs to text and currently I am using `pdftotext.exe`. This messes up the resulting text sometimes and so I can't use that.

Is there another free tool that I can call from another program? I'd prefer a command line tool.

Comment: try this one: https://github.com/luochen1990/nodejs-easy-pdf-parser

Answer (score 3):

PDF can be tricky to convert to Text depending on how its constructed, but you may get good results from iTextSharp or GhostScript or a commercial component eg: from www.tallcomponents.com (not affiliated)

Comment: Can iTextSharp also convert from PDF to TXT?

Comment: It can extract text, see here for an example and other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711134/itextsharp-text-extraction

Answer (score 1):

PDF files do not generally contain any structure so the software needs to guess it. I wrote a blog post on the issues at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/

You could also try PdfBox.

Answer (score 0):

I find that [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is much better than pdftotext. It extracts text in a way that is much closer to the original formatting of the document. It can be run from the command line.