# find page number of a string in pdf file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am developing a pdf reader. i want to find any string in pdf and to know the corresponding page number. I am using iTextSharp.

Comment: You'll need to extract text from every page, check out PdfTextExtractor, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4893285/231316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// add any string you want to match on
Regex regex = new Regex("the", 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled 
);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
  ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.ProcessContent(
    i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
  );
  if ( regex.IsMatch(strategy.GetResultantText()) ) {
    // do whatever with corresponding page number i...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Itextsharp` you can use `Acrobat.dll` to find the current page number. First of all open the pdf file and search the string usingL

```
Acroavdoc.open("Filepath","Temperory title")
```

and

```
Acroavdoc.FindText("String").
```

If the string found in this pdf file then the cursor moved into the particular page and the searched string will be highlighted. Now we use `Acroavpageview.GetPageNum()` to get the current page number.

```
Dim AcroXAVDoc As CAcroAVDoc
Dim Acroavpage As AcroAVPageView
Dim AcroXApp As CAcroApp

AcroXAVDoc = CType(CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc"), Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc)
AcroXApp = CType(CreateObject("AcroExch.App"), Acrobat.CAcroApp)
AcroXAVDoc.Open(TextBox1.Text, "Original document")
AcroXAVDoc.FindText("String is to searched", True, True, False)
Acroavpage = AcroXAVDoc.GetAVPageView()

Dim x As Integer = Acroavpage.GetPageNum
MsgBox("the string found in page number" & x)
```