# Need to extract text line by line from PDF using itextsharp and put enter at every end of line

Tags: itext

I got this function of `itextsharp library` to extract pdf text line by line:

```
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
```

...but I need to put `ENTER` at every line every **end of line** of pdf even if there is empty row it should read empty row.

Comment: `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage` **does** put end-of-line markers at the end of every line it recognizes (cf. the method `GetResultantText` of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`: `sb.Append('\n');`). That being said there generally *is no **end of line** or **row** in a PDF!* Therefore, if iText's heuristics for *interpreting such concepts into the PDF page content* don't work for you, you may need a custom `TextExtractionStrategy` implementation. If you need help with that, please give more details, especially what you get, what you want, and a sample PDF illustrating your issue.

Comment: +1 for @mkl: There is no such thing as 'a line' in a PDF, nor is there such a thing as 'ENTER'. Content is added at absolute positions; it isn't organized in lines.

Answer (score 4):

read into a string variable then split
e.g.  String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);

```
String[] s1 = page.split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following Links:

1. http://api.itextpdf.com/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html
2. link of stack-overflow: [Itextsharp text extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711134/itextsharp-text-extraction?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Concerning the stack overflow link: Please make clear that you indeed want to refer to the answers making use of the `PdfTextExtractor` class.