# How to read data from table-structured PDF using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I am having a problem with reading some data from pdf file.
My file is structurized and it contains tables and plain text. Standard parser reads data from separate columns at the same line. For example:

```
Some Table Header  
Data Col1a     Data Col2a      Data Col3a
Data Col1b     Data Col2b      Data Col3b
               Data Col2c
```

with this code

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfName);

        List<String> text = new List<String>();
        String page;
        List<String> pageStrings;
        string[] separators = { "\n", "\r\n" };

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
            pageStrings = new List<string>(page.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            text.AddRange(pageStrings);

        }

        reader.Close();

        return text;
```

will be concatenated into strings:

```
Some Table Header
Data Col1a Data Col2a Data Col3a  
Data Col1b Data Col2b Data Col3b  
Data Col2c
```

I'd like to get concatenated strings that will reflect data from blocks. I'd like to get such strings for upper example:

```
Some Table Header
Data Col1a Data Col1b   
Data Col2a Data Col2b Data Col2c  
Data Col3a Data Col3b
```

Does anyone have any idea how to tune itextsharp to get such behavior of pdf parser?
Maybe someone has appropriate code sample?
The sample PDF file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwsuu6mz9ez84ss/sampleFile.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Try using the [`LocationTextExtractionStrategy`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4893285/231316)

Comment: Your allegation that the PDF is *table structured* is false if the PDF isn't a Tagged PDF. So the real question is: is your PDF a Tagged PDF? If the answer is no, then your eyes are deceiving you. You *see* a table with your *human eyes*, but to a machine there is no table. A machine can only "see" text and lines at arbitrary places.

Comment: You can tune it by telling it where the columns are, i.e. by filtering by coordinates.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie, another one tool parse my PDF exactly like I want. So I think that PDF is really table structured. PS: this tool is pdfbox

Comment: Have you tried the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` instead of the default `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`?  And can share the PDF in question? You ask for an appropriate code sample. That's only feasible for a given sample file.

Comment: mkl, thank You for your assistance! I'll try to attach sample file to the question

Comment: mkl, update was done, link to the sample file is in the start post

Comment: (All the empty pages in between are there intentionally?)

Comment: No. Originally this file contains private data. I've made some changes on first and last pages, other pages just cleared.

Comment: *I've made some changes on first and last pages* - I hope these changes did not change the extraction properties... Anyways, I'll write an answer demonstrating how to get the same output with iText(Sharp) as with PDFBox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OP's sample file contains multiple sections like this one:

[image: sampleFile.pdf, top of page 1]

And the OP mentioned in a comment:

> another one tool parse my PDF exactly like I want. [...]
>
> PS: this tool is pdfbox

Using PDFBox (v1.8.10, the current release version) in this method:

```
String extract(PDDocument document) throws IOException
{
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    return stripper.getText(document);
}
```

returns for the section shown above

```
Driver Book for 8/5/2015
Company IS MEDICAL; AND Date of Service IS BETWEEN 08/05/2015 AND 08/05/2015; AND Status IS Assigned; AND Vehicles IS  MEDICAL: 
CATY
 MEDICAL
Trip #: 314-A
Comments: ----LIVERY---
Destination:Pick-up:
Call Type: Livery
<Doctor Office>
REGO PARK,  (631) 
000-0000
(718) 896-5953
74- AVE 204E  HEIGHTS, NY 
11372 (718) 639-4154
11:00:00 PAT, MIKHAIL
Trip #: 314-B
Comments:  ----LIVERY---
Destination:Pick-up:
Call Type: Livery
74- AVE 204E  HEIGHTS, NY 
11372 (718) 639-4154
<Doctor Office>
63-6 REGO PARK, NY 
11374 (631) 000-0000
11:01:00 PAT, MIKHAIL
```

This is not really a neat column-wise extraction but certain blocks of information (like address blocks) remain together.

Getting the same output with iText(Sharp) actually is very easy: One merely has to explicitly use the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` instead of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` which is used by default, i.e. one has to replace this line

```
page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
```

by

```
page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
```

With the exception of one space character per dataset (iText(Sharp) extracts `Destination: Pick-up:` instead of `Destination:Pick-up:`) the results are identical.

---

Concerning your conclusion from PDFBox extracting the text as it does:

> So I think that PDF is really table structured.

Actually this order of extraction means merely that the operations for drawing the string segments in the PDF page content stream occur in this very order. As the order of those operations is arbitrary according to the PDF specification, any update of the software generating those PDFs may result in files from which the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper`  and the iText `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` extract merely an unintelligible soup of characters.

---

PS: If one sets the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` property `SortByPosition` to `true` like this

```
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    return stripper.getText(document);
```

then PDFBox extracts the text just like iText(Sharp) with the (default) `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` does

---

The OP indicated interest in a block structure inherent in the content stream. The most obvious structure like that in a generic PDF would be the text objects (in which multiple strings may be drawn).

In the case at hand the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` is used. It can easily be extended to also include markers corresponding to the start and end of text objects in its output. In Java this can be done by using an anonymous class like this:

```
return PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, pageNo, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
{
    boolean empty = true;

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock()
    {
        if (!empty)
            appendTextChunk("<BLOCK>");
        super.beginTextBlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock()
    {
        if (!empty)
            appendTextChunk("</BLOCK>\n");
        super.endTextBlock();
    }

    @Override
    public String getResultantText()
    {
        if (empty)
            return super.getResultantText();
        else
            return "<BLOCK>" + super.getResultantText();
    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        empty = false;
        super.renderText(renderInfo);
    }
});
```

*([TextExtraction.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/TextExtraction.java) method `extractSimple`)*

(This Java code should easily be translatable into C#. The playing around with an `empty` boolean may look funny; it is necessary, though, because the base class assumes certain additional properties to be set as soon as some chunk has been appended to the extracted content.)

Using this extended strategy one gets for the section shown above:

```
<BLOCK>Driver Book for 8/5/2015
Company IS MEDICAL; AND Date of Service IS BETWEEN 08/05/2015 AND 08/05/2015; AND Status IS Assigned; AND Vehicles IS  MEDICAL: 
CATY</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
 MEDICAL</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Trip #: 314-A</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Comments: ----LIVERY---</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Destination: Pick-up:</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Call Type: Livery
<Doctor Office>
REGO PARK,  (631) 
000-0000
(718) 896-5953</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
74- AVE 204E  HEIGHTS, NY 
11372 (718) 639-4154</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
11:00:00</BLOCK>
<BLOCK> PAT, MIKHAIL</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Trip #: 314-B</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Comments:  ----LIVERY---</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Destination: Pick-up:</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
Call Type: Livery
74- AVE 204E  HEIGHTS, NY 
11372 (718) 639-4154</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
<Doctor Office>
63-6 REGO PARK, NY 
11374 (631) 000-0000</BLOCK>
<BLOCK>
11:01:00</BLOCK>
<BLOCK> PAT, MIKHAIL</BLOCK>
```

As this keeps addresses in the same block, this might help during extraction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I used strategy SimpleTextExtractionStrategy that was mentioned above.  But your answer is full and great! Thank you one more time.
PS: from your answer I see that you have an idea of how to get blocks more comfortable, just like this sample:
<pre>
Driver Book for 8/5/2015
 MEDICAL
Trip #: 314-A
Comments: ----LIVERY---
Pick-up:
74- AVE 204E HEIGHTS, NY 11372
(718)639-4154
Destination:
<Doctor Office>REGO PARK, (631)000-0000(718)896-5953
</pre>

Comment: I can't post in formatted view, unfortunately... Tag <pre> doesn't work :(
Actually I mean that blocks with addresses can be located one-by-one in the resulting String's list. Am I right? Can you give me advise how to change code to achieve this goal?
PS: that PDF was generated by third-party tool, I can't change anything with it...

Comment: The blocks I mentioned were merely recognized by me as a human, not by some software. As explained in the answer, the order of the text elements is the order of the matching operators in the content stream. One might sometimes deduce some context from the exact flow of operators but your edits changed that flow, so I cannot tell whether there are some hints in the original file.

Comment: But I changed only pages after first... On first page I changed some data inside blocks without changing blocks structure.

Comment: I'll have a look but cannot guarantee anything. Chances are, though, that I won't have the time today.

Comment: Thank you for Your help in any cases! You're really StackOverflow "Maniac" (c) :)

Comment: *On first page I changed some data inside blocks without changing blocks structure.* - I'm afraid those changes *did* change the internal block structure. Everywhere you changed something, a marked-content point tagged **TouchUp_TextEdit** has been inserted, and inserting a marked-content point required leaving the current text object and starting a new one thereafter. Thus, I don't know which text object transitions are from your original file and which were introduced by your changes.

Comment: That been said, though, `Call Type: Livery` is in the same text object as `<Doctor Office>` and `REGO PARK, (631)`; thus, there isn't a text object dedicated to that address.

Comment: Actually, `<Doctor Office>` and `REGO PARK, (631)` are originally in the same text object. I can't be sure about `Call Type: Livery`

Comment: I added some information to the answer explaining how to extract text object barriers, too. It is in Java but should easily be translated.

Comment: mkl, i don't have words to describe my admiration! Thank you for your help! I have a lot of work with PDF files in the future, so, your help will be very important for me!