# Add additional column in pdf table

Tags: c#, itext

I need to add additional column in specific table and place modified table in .pdf file instead of originial one. Simple steps are following:

1. Get table from pdf file
2. Edit this table in corresponding way
3. Remove original table from pdf
4. Insert modified table

Could anyone share links or ideas how can I do this? 
Thanks.

[image: The image from a comment]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is [pdf example](https://expirebox.com/download/9b3e6f60ea8706481bd06d0124346f51.html) and [image of what I need](https://expirebox.com/download/95e7e084037858e92e2635025257c917.html)

Comment: The problem is I don't have any code. I found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014589/how-to-read-data-from-table-structured-pdf-using-itextsharp) of how to get table data. But do not find any examples of how to replace original table with modified.

Comment: You cannot *"Get table from pdf file"* because there is no table in the PDF: In the PDF there only are assorted lines and text chunks arranged in a way we recognize as a table, but there is no explicit table structure.

Answer (score 1):

An idea that I can give you is:

_ Use a program that convert pdf in txt

_ Work on txt (with c#,java, ecc) and remove the column you want

_ use a program that convert txt in pdf

All in a project that call the converter programs and elaborate the columns